# control increase or decrease contrast MATLAB

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing

How to know when i should increase or decrease contrast in image? for example some images need to decrease and some need to increase. so how can i control that in matlab?
Could studying histogram help me ?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps using [imadjust](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/images/ref/imadjust.html) is what you are looking for.

Comment: Or you also might want to look at [imcontrast](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/images/ref/imcontrast.html)

Comment: yea it is. but imadjust helps in some pictures and doesnt in other. i need an adaptive way, where i should know when i should do increment for the contrast and when to do decrement

Comment: i would try to look for something with histogram equalization. or any other type of scaling.